# Adobe illustrator - how to achieve "dissolving" icon effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, technique

I have this simple icon:

[image]

And I would like to apply a kind of "dissolve" aesthetic to it, for reference:

[image]

However I cannot think of any way to achieve this in a human time-frame. I hope there is some labor-saving approach to break my icon up into blocks, from which point I can delete and move around as desired.

### Question

What is the least labor-intensive approach for this technique in AI?

**Note:** you may assume a black fill (probably will give us a clearer dissolve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a start to understand the process. Make your own modifications to achieve the desired effect.

Rasterize the object. (the blurred object is just a test of the effect).

Go to Object > Create Object Mosaic...

Play with the values. Remember to add some value to Tile Spacing.

Now you have a bunch of squares to play with.

See the images below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get part of the way there via Astute Graphic's [**Phantasm Plug in**](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/phantasm) and Ai's built in **Transform Each** function.

Base art:

[image]

Select and use `Effect > Phantasm > Halftone` in the Menu with the [Phantasm Plug in](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/phantasm) Installed. (there is a free trial available for this paid plug in, but it's also one of the few plugins I feel is worth every penny they want).

[image]

Note I have the options for the plug in set to **Square** for the shape.

This results in artwork split into little squares...

[image]

`Object > Expand Appearance` then `Object > Ungroup` from the menu.

Then choose `Object > Transform > Transform Each` from the menu. Tick the **Random** option and adjust the **Move** sliders.

[image]

Resulting in random dispersement of the squares... The amount of dispersion depends upon the values of the move sliders in the Transform Each dialog.

[image]

From here it's a matter of simply moving things.

I **think** there's a script somewhere to move objects based on a given point but I'm unable to find anything at this time.

---

If you use `Transform Each` in steps you can get some closer results...

[image]

---

Also if you alter artwork and adjust some of the **Phantasm** settings you can achieve the size variation of the squares. Here, I've added 20% grey stroke to the art before using the plug in. the decreased value causes the plug in to create smaller "dots" for the halftone effect. I also adjusted the curve the plug in uses.

[image]

---

<sub>Disclosure: I have no stake or investment in Astute Graphics or their Phantasm plug in. I have however, been given software free of charge from Astute Graphics in exchange for my evaluation and/or opinions.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you want some kind of disintegrating, the splinters should have random sizes, placements and rotations. That can be achieved easily with a symbol sprayer. You can have a few predrawn splinter shapes. Spray one set to make holes to the main shape. You can make holes with boolean subtract or simply setting the colors = the background color. Then spray another set wit the same color as your main shape has. If it has two colors, spray two sets.

An example:

[image]

This is in Inkscape, because I found there is easier to select what I want to spray. The size is randomized in sprayer's options, but I had only one predrawn splinter shape - a circle. Nothing prevents one have more shapes and allow random rotations, too.

**Not asked:** If you bother to work with high resolution raster image in Photoshop, you can blow splinters out of a shape with displacement map. Let the map have base color = 50% grey (= no displacement) insert to the same map layer splinters which are clipped from a gradient to get varying displacement distances.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your image broken up into the cubes, you should be able to scatter them with "transform each."

Object>Transform>Transform Each

[image: transform each]

Under the move section, add a percentage for horizontal and vertical movement, andn maybe add rotation or scale to make it seem more forceful. Check preview to see how it's looking.